# Error in xml file, TestNG content handler

Tags: xml

I don't have much knowledge about xml file. I am trying to execute the TestNG through xml file.. Its shows following error before adding the suggested line at top of the program.. 
eroor: 
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.

After adding the recommended line its shows the following error:

org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

following is the xml file..

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> (shows error at this line) 
<suite name= "anyname">
<tests name = "FirstTest">
<test name = "Get Products Info and price">
<classes> 

<class name = "packageName.classN">

</class>
</classes>
<groups>
    <run>
      <include name="Part1"/>
    </run>
  </groups>

</test>
</tests>

</suite>
```

Comment: Delete first line and make sure the '<?' is at the beginning of the file.  Then add missing last line : </suite>

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer.. After removing the fire line the following message pops up.. Error:: [TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
Excel DataIphone Cover

Comment: Then put it on the 2nd line.  It cannot be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The second line should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

This line should be the first line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Please consider improving your response by adding a bit more explanation & context as of why it would work.